# Power BI Gateway Connection without Internet Connection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datagateway

I want to connect with online power BI and create reports using Data gateway connectivity. my Problem is Internet Connectivity. I don't have the internet in the Production environment. Is it possible without the internet?

If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with [Azure ExpressRoute with Microsoft Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-circuit-peerings), but the network configuration is somewhat complex.  It's much more common to get a firewall exception for the Gateway VM, or to run the Gateway VM in an Azure VNet and connect back to on-prem data sources through ExpressRoute.